# Type of a removed pointer to function member

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers

The type of:

```
std::remove_pointer<int(*)(int)>::type
```

is `int(int)`. This code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout << boolalpha;
   cout << is_same<remove_pointer<int(*)(int)>, int(int)>::value;
   cout << endl;
}
```

prints 'true'. But, what is the (written) type of a "function member"?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_trais>

using namespace std;

struct A {};

int main()
{
    cout << boolalpha;
    cout << is_same<remove_pointer<int(A::*)(int)>, int(int)>::value;
    cout << endl;
}
```

returns `false`. And something like `int A::(int)` throws a compilation error (invalid type).

Answer (score 3):

A pointer-to-member is not a pointer.

`remove_pointer` won't change the type.

- Demo: http://ideone.com/OiGGpf

Comment: And why a "pointer" to member isn't a "pointer"? It has no sense.

Comment: A "pointer" is an address of some object (or function) in memory.  A pointer-to-member is not.  It is the information necessary to find the address of a subobject (or member function) given a pointer to the parent object.  Without a parent object, there is no subobject, and no pointer.

Answer (score 3):

It goes like this: A non-member type is either an object or a function type:

```
T = int;                 // object type
T = double(char, bool)   // function type
```

For non-static class members, you can only have *pointer-to-member* types. Those are of the form:

```
class Foo;

PM = U Foo::*;           // pointer to member type
```

The question is what `U` is:

```
U = int                 =>  PM = int Foo::*                  // pointer-to-member-object
U = double(char, bool)  =>  PM = double (Foo::*)(char, bool) // pointer-to-member-function
```

A "pointer-to-member" is not a pointer, and so you cannot "remove the pointer" from it. At best you can get the underlying type, i.e. go from `PM = U Foo::*` to `U`. To my knowledge, no such trait exists, but it is easily concocted:

```
template <typename> struct remove_member_pointer;

template <typename U, typename F> struct remove_member_pointer<U F::*>
{
    typedef U member_type; 
    typedef F class_type;
};
```